# css inline don't work with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap but the col-md thing doesn't seem work. I want to inline 3 things - input, drop down and a button.

demo http://plnkr.co/edit/0zNftdDhbGxzV2sVlMQp?p=preview

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a bit of how twitter bootstrap works, here is some info on how to use their grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I also made a working plnkr, altho you might want to change the size of the colums. :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/nzfUlLxkNU0qXhy2HFTz?p=preview